# Node.JS cannot find module 'xml2js' (Windows)

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Need to do parsing xml-file using Node.js.

Using a library for parsing [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js).

Xml2js installed using the command "npm install xml2js".

However, if you run the code:

```
var fs = require ('fs'), xml2js = require ('xml2js'); 

var parser = new xml2js.Parser (); 
fs.readFile ('<path to the xml-file>', function (err, data) {
     parser.parseString (data, function (err, result) {
         console.dir (result); 
         console.log ('Done'); 
     }); 
});
```

an error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'xml2js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<путь до js-файла>:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Tell me, please, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that the directory `./node_modules/xml2js` exists.

When you run `npm install somemodule` at `D:/test`, it will be stored to `D:/test/node_modules/somemodule`, then you can require this module in `D:/test/*.js`, and you can not require it at `D:/other/place/*.js`. If you hope the module can be required anywhere you should run:

```
npm install somemodule -g
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Created a folder "node_modules" and moved into it the necessary files. Additionally had to install modules "sax" and "xmlbuilder". Only now after installing xmlbuilder and transfer the entire folder "xmlbuilder-js-master" in the folder "node_modules" try to run js-file error occurs "cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'". Tell me, please, why the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the situation on you computer. First, you do not need to create manually, npm will create it automatically. you can have a look about the modules by `npm list`, and if you module did not install correctly, you will see some red words. To solve the incorrectly installation you can use `cd node_modules/somemodule && npm install`, the command `npm install` will read the local package.json file to check installation or fix the dependencies

Comment: **UPD:** To connect "xmlbuilder" must first move previously downloaded folder "xmlbuilder-js-master" in "node_modules", then rename "xmlbuilder-js-master" in "xmlbuilder" and then execute the command in the console "npm install xmlbuilder". Finally, after this js-code file parser run correctly.

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing the same issue. Here's what I did:

Install the module using following:

`$ npm install -g *module_name*`

Then go to any parent dir of your project dir (it can be project dir itself) and run the following command:

`$ npm link *module_name*`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and even tried the fix mentioned by Lellansin, but it didnt help. There were some issues with npm cache and I had to clear it using the command:

npm cache clean

And it worked for me.